# OSX changing backgrounds- iphoto folder doesn't update

Tags: macos, photos.app, desktop

I have the background image on my OSX desktop set to change every x minutes- it chooses a random image within a specific iPhoto album.

However, when I remove photos from that iPhoto album, the removed pictures continue to cycle on my desktop.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Does it persist after rebooting?

Comment: @the Yes. I've rebooted many times since I started pruning pics from that iphoto folder.